# gnu make, vpath rule, all but one file

Tags: gnu, gnu-make

It happens to need to compile all *.c files from one folder, except one, which has exactlly the same name and is compiled from somwhere else. I solved by giving vpath for each file I want separately

```
vpath   plant.c $(KMLROOT)/examples/$(KML_FLAVOUR)/pdk
vpath   app.c $(KMLROOT)/examples/$(KML_FLAVOUR)/pdk
vpath   app_test.c $(KMLROOT)/examples/$(KML_FLAVOUR)/pdk
vpath   app_echo.c $(KMLROOT)/examples/$(KML_FLAVOUR)/pdk
```

Now if I write

```
vpath   %.c $(KMLROOT)/examples/$(KML_FLAVOUR)/pdk
```

The file that I don't want to include will be on path.

There is a possibility to write some rule and exclude specific file?

Comment: It seems useless to use vpath in this way. If you have to specify a path for every individual file why not just use the pathname directly.

Comment: because there is a file on that path with the same name with one that i have locally. I want my file, and all the files in that folder except that file. A crude fix is to delete duplicate file but this is a pdk from 3'rd party and I don't want to delete files from it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I'm saying why use vpath?  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide a specific path for every file, then vpath is useless.

Since you don't give any other information about what you do with the source files, I can't give a complete example, but why don't you just do something like:

```
KMLSRC = plant.c app.c app_test.c app_echo.c

KML_FULLSRC = $(addprefix $(KMLROOT)/examples/$(KML_FLAVOUR)/,$(KMLSRC))
```